# Styling a particular HTML code with CSS

Tags: html, css, styles

I need to apply a css style that only catches this piece of code:

```
<div id="box-article-r">
 <h2>
  <a id="metodo-pago" href="#">Payment Methods...
```

On the same page I have for instance a lot of h2, some other code with the ids "metodo-pago" and "box-article-r" also some "a" tags and some combination of them but none of them it is at the same time inside "#box-article-r" and "h2" and "a" and "#metodo-pago". I have tried this and a few similar combinations but nothings has worked so far for me:

```
#box-article-r h2 a #metodo-pago{
  display: none;
}
```

I can not modify the HTML, just the CSS.
I am not an expert in CSS so this is to complex for my CSS knowledge. Can any one please help me?
Regards

Comment: `some other code with the ids "metodo-pago" and "box-article-r"` means you have invalid HTML; an `id` must be unique within the page.

Comment: Just check more then one id have a same name html need separate ids.try to give display:none at inline.

Comment: I did not do the page code, the page is done by someone else (a company) and I do not have access to change the HTML. Just the CSS, I thought it was clear when is said: "I can not modify the HTML"

Answer (score 1):

`a #metodo-pago` means a having child element with id `metodo-pago`

whereas,

`a#metodo-pago` means a having id `metodo-pago`

Write:

```
#box-article-r h2 a#metodo-pago{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove space between `a` and `id`

```
a#metodo-pago
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's just say that you should not have more than one ID with the same name on the same page. I would rather refactor my code so that this is not the case.

If you need to have the same name for each of the  tags, rather use a class name instead of an ID.

The below code will assist with your issue to a degree, but remember that it is based on flawed HTML content.

```
#box-article-r h2 #metodo-pago {
    display: none;
}
```

Should you wish to use a class instead of an ID as explained, rather change your code to this:

```
<div class="box-article-r">
    <h2>
        <a class="metodo-pago" href="#">Payment Methods...
```

And target it with CSS as follows:

```
.box-article-r h2 a.metodo-pago {
    display: none;
}
```